# edit content of index.html in jhipster

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I'm getting a problem with editing the home page of my project created with jHipster. The content in index.html comes from

```
<div class="well" ui-view="content"></div>
```

I want to give my own content in the body for this, where should I do changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because we use Angular Translate by default.

- Either remove the "translate" directive, and change the content of the file directly
- Or have a look at the translations in the `src/main/webapp/i18n` directory, and change the text there